# Formulario HTML con AJAX, JSON y PHP al cambiar estado de Borrador a Publicada No funciona, retorna 404

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax, json

Mi pregunta es acerca de un formulario que está probado en el entorno de una página web, para realizar unas funciones de mantenimiento de datos, utilizo HTML con código de JavaScript para realizar una búsqueda de datos a través de una función que uso con AJAX para obtener los datos de un Socio de la BB.dd de Mysql, del que se informa el dni y en la llamada a esta función obtiene datos personales que se muestran en los input, o se emite el mensaje oportuno de Socio No existe Créalo.
Se comporta correctamente en el estado de BORRADOR cuando lo cambio a PUBLICADO no funciona, en la llamada a la función con uso de AJAX para obtener datos de un módulo PHP, en el retorno siempre se bifurca por error: function(), consultado el log devuelve 404.

El código del Formulario con las funciones de JavaScript lo incluyo a continuación.

```
 <html>
<head>
<title>PROBANDO PARA SENDATOLEDO</title>
</head>
<body>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.js"></script>
 <div class="container">
<div class="cargando row">       
  <div class="d-flex justify-content-center">
    <div class="spinner-border text-primary" role="status">
      <span class="visually-hidden">Cargando...</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
  <div class="formulario row">
  <!-- INICIA LA COLUMNA -->
    <div class="col-md-4 offset-md-2">
      <center><h1>DNI</h1></center>
      <form>
        <!--Campo Documento-->
        <div class="mb-2">
          <label for="dni">Dni</label></br>
          <input type="text" name="dni" class="form-control" id="dni" onblur="buscar();">
        </div>
        <!--Campo Nombre-->
        <div class="mb-3">
            <label for="nombre">Nombre </label>
            <input type="text" name="nombre" class="form-control" id="nombre"> 
        </div>
        <!--Campo Dirección-->
        <div class="mb-4">
            <label for="dom_pobla">Dirección </label>
            <input type="text" name="dom_pobla" class="form-control" id="dom_pobla">
        </div>
      <!--Campo IBAN-->
        <div class="mb-4">
            <label for="iban">IBAN </label>
            <input type="text" name="iban" class="form-control" id="iban">
        </div>
        <!--Campo Teléfono-->
        <div class="mb-3">
            <label for="tfno_mov">Teléfono </label>
            <input type="text" name="tfno_mov" class="form-control" id="tfno_mov">
        </div>
        <!--Botones-->
        <center>
          <input type="button" value="ENVIAR" class="btn btn-success" name="btn_enviar" onclick="guardar();">
          <input type="button" value="CANCELAR" class="btn btn-danger" name="btn_cancelar" onclick="limpiar();">
        </center>
      </form>
      <div class="resultados"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

la parte de JavaScript

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
$('.cargando').hide();
});  

function buscar()
    {
    var parametros = 
    {
    "buscar": "1",
    "dni" : $("#dni").val()
    };
    $.ajax(
    {
      type:'post',
      data: parametros,
      url:'00_codigos_php.php',
      dataType: 'json',

  beforeSend: function() 
  {
    $('.formulario').hide();
    $('.cargando').show();
    }, 
    error: function()
    {alert("Error data en linea 87 a 9x.....");},
  complete: function() 
    {
    $('.formulario').show();
    $('.cargando').hide();
    },
  success: function (data) 
  {
    if(data.existe =="SI")
        {
        $("#nombre").val(data.nombre);
        $("#dom_pobla").val(data.dom_pobla);
        $("#iban").val(data.iban);
        $("#tfno_mov").val(data.tfno_mov);
        }
    else
        {
        alert('HTML_El SOCIO no existe, ¡Crealo! !!' );
        limpiar();          
        }     
  } 
})
}
function limpiar()
    {
    //$("#dni").val("");
    $("#nombre").val("");
    $("#iban").val("");
    $("#dom_pobla").val("");
    $("#tfno_mov").val("");
    }

function guardar()
    {
    var parametros = 
        {
        "guardar": "1",
        "dni" : $("#dni").val(),
        "nombre" : $("#nombre").val(),
        "iban" : $("#iban").val(),
        "tfno_mov" : $("#tfno_mov").val(),
        "dom_pobla" : $("#dom_pobla").val()
        };
    $.ajax(
        {
        data:  parametros,
        url:   '00_codigos_php.php',
        type:  'post',
        beforeSend: function() 
        {
        $('.formulario').hide();
        $('.cargando').show();

    }, 
error: function()
    {alert("Error");},
complete: function() 
    {
    $('.formulario').show();
    $('.cargando').hide();
    },
success: function (mensaje) 
    {$('.resultados').html(mensaje);}
    }) 
limpiar();
}
```

Comment: por favor añade código y logs a la pregunta

Answer (score 1):

Resuelta la incidencia, el cambio de Borrador, que funcionaba correctamente, a Publicada con un 404, se resuelva tan facil como añadir toda la URL donde se encontra el PHP, ej:

```
    url:'https://www.paginaweb.es/00_codigos_php.php',
```